# Unable to parse the strptime in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am converting the datetime into time. My JSON datetime format is "`2017-01-02T19:00:07.9181202Z`". I have placed my code below:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_format = datetime.strptime('2017-01-02T19:00:07.9181202Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
time = date_format.strftime("%I:%M %p")
print(time)
```

Error message as below:

[image]

After that I read this [python date-time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) document. It says that microsecond digit should be 6. But, JSON date-time microsecond has 7 digit.

**Message from Python document:**

> `%f` is an extension to the set of format characters in the C standard
>   (but implemented separately in datetime objects, and therefore always
>   available). When used with the `strptime()` method, the `%f` directive
>   accepts from one to six digits and zero pads on the right.

I need result like `07:00 PM` format. Is there any alternative method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that the input will always be like that, you can just remove the extra digit before passing that string to `strptime`:

```
date_format = datetime.strptime('2017-01-02T19:00:07.9181202Z'[:-2] + 'Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

This is dirty, but gives the idea - remove the last two characters (the extra digit and "Z"), re-add the "Z".